# Why isn't my error type changed automatically when using the and_then combinator?

Tags: rust

I have encountered something that I don't understand about `Result`, `From`, `and_then`.

I have this function in my `impl Parser` that will give me either a slice of bytes or a `ParseError` when there are not enough bytes:

```
fn consume_bytes(self: &mut Parser<'a>, len: usize) -> Result<&[u8], ParseError> {
    // ...
}
```

I'm trying to define another function:

```
fn read_utf8(self: &mut Parser<'a>, len: usize) -> Result<String, ParseError> {
    self.consume_bytes(len)
        .and_then(|bytes| String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec()))
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/parser.rs:147:31
    |
147 |             .and_then(|bytes| String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec()))
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `parser::ParseError`, found struct `std::string::FromUtf8Error`
    |
    = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, parser::ParseError>`
               found type `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::string::FromUtf8Error>`
```

Because I have defined an implementation of `From`, I was expecting the conversion to be performed automatically, since by using the `try!` macro the conversion is automatic (from what I've understood):

```
impl From<FromUtf8Error> for ParseError {
    fn from(err: FromUtf8Error) -> ParseError {
        ParseError::InvalidConstantPoolEntry(err)
    }
}
```

This is another attempt that fails with the same error message:

```
fn read_utf8(self: &mut Parser<'a>, len: usize) -> Result<String, ParseError> {
    self.consume_bytes(len)
        .and_then(|bytes| String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec()))
        .map_err(|e| From::from(e))
}
```

This version, where the `map_err` is *inside* the `and_then` lambda, works:

```
fn read_utf8(self: &mut Parser<'a>, len: usize) -> Result<String, ParseError> {
    self.consume_bytes(len)
        .and_then(|bytes| String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec()).map_err(|e| From::from(e)))
}
```

Why doesn't `and_then` work as I expected?

---

PS: What's more idiomatic: the version I'm trying to write above or using the `?` operator/the `try!` macro?

```
fn read_utf8(self: &mut Parser<'a>, len: usize) -> Result<String, ParseError> {
    let bytes = self.consume_bytes(len)?;
    Ok(String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec())?)
}
```

Comment: you can just write: `.map_err(From::from)`

Comment: [One question per post, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: I will say that `self: &mut Parser<'a>` is **not** idiomatic, that's normally `&mut self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting the conversion to be performed automatically, since by using the `try!` macro the conversion is automatic (from what I've understood).

But you aren't *using* the `try!` macro!

```
fn read_utf8(self: &mut Parser<'a>, len: usize) -> Result<String, ParseError> {
    self.consume_bytes(len)
        .and_then(|bytes| String::from_utf8(bytes.to_vec()))
}
```

Code that you aren't calling cannot have any effect on your code, thankfully.

---

Review the signature for [`Result::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then):

```
fn and_then<U, F>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E> 
    where F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E>
```

It takes a closure that returns a `Result` with the **same error type** that we started with. There is no automatic conversion of error types happening here. There *may* be some conversion of the success type, depending on what the closure chooses to do.

This is why your version that converts the error type inside `and_then` works, because you've converted the error type from `FromUtf8Error` to `ParseError`, making the error type returned by the closure match what `and_then` expects.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the part about the signature.
I've also taken a look at [the real `try!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#the-real-try-macro) macro and now I think I understand much better.